# How to use microphone and webcam in Qemu?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I'm running Artix Linux and using Qemu & KVM to emulate Windows 10. I need to enable the support of my microphone and usb webcam. I've tried to first to pass the webcam via Virtmanager, my VM sees the webcam, but I can not get any video feed from. Also I can not get any sound input in my VM. I've tried launching it from the console:
`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 4096 -rtc base=localtime  -hda /path/win10.qcow2 -cpu host -device hda-duplex -device usb-host, hostbus=<n>, hostaddr=<m>, id=<id>`
But I get this error:
`drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists`
Please, help, I don't know what to do.

Comment: It sounds simpler to install VirtualBox and just click in the gui.

Comment: need to be more elaborate

Comment: Were you able to fix the microphone issue?

Comment: Yep, im running artix with qemu and kvm, i strongly advice to first check all of the permissons and privacy settings on windows machine. And it works better with virtmanager.  If your default devices dont work then just buy a webcam, there are many models on the market, just pick one with a microphone build in. Then reddirect it via virtmanager, it should work fine after that.